# Problems of the sandwich menu compared to pointer filling

Tags: html, css

What happens is, that in the sandwich menu the white filling of the whole box is displayed, when the page is loaded and when you indicate with the mouse cursor to select it disappears.

Here the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black;">
      <style type="text/css">
           .sidebarBtn{    
              color: #fff;
              font-size: 22px;
              position: absolute;
              right: 30px;
              top: 25px;
              z-index: 101;
              cursor: pointer;
              display: none;
              height: 16px; /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
              width: 27px;
              border-top: 2px solid #fff;
              display: block;
              border: none;  
              height: 26px; /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
              top: 25px;
              outline: 10px solid transparent;
            }

            .sidebarBtn span{
              height: 2px;
              width: 100%;
              display: block;  
              position: absolute;
              top: 50%;
              left: 0;
              background: #fff;
              margin-top: -1px;
              -webkit-transition: background 0 0.3s;
              transition: background 0 0.3s;  
            }

            .sidebarBtn span:before,
            .sidebarBtn span:after{
              content: '';
              position: absolute;
              left: 0;
              height: 2px;
              width: 100%;
              background: #fff;
              display: block;
              -webkit-transition:bottom 0.30s linear,top 0.30s linear; 
              -moz-transition:bottom 0.30s linear,top 0.30s linear; 
              -o-transition:bottom 0.30s linear,top 0.30s linear; 
              transition:bottom 0.30s linear,top 0.30s linear;

              -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
                -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
                transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
            }

            .sidebarBtn span:before{ 
              top: -8px;  
              -webkit-transition-property: top, -webkit-transform;
              -moz-transition-property: top, -moz-transform;
              transition-property: top, transform;
            }

            .sidebarBtn span:after{

             bottom: -8px;
                -webkit-transition-property: bottom, -webkit-transform;
                -moz-transition-property: bottom, -moz-transform;
                transition-property: bottom, transform;
            }

            .sidebarBtn:hover{
                background:rgba(255,255,255,.15);
                outline-color:rgba(255,255,255,.15);
            }               

      </style>
      <button class="sidebarBtn">
        <span></span>
      </button>
</body>
</html>
```

What I do want is to tell me where the fault is and how I can solve it, since I want to remove the filling and only the visualization of the sandwich menu remains.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `background: transparent` to the css class of the button:

```
.sidebarBtn{    
              color: #fff;
              font-size: 22px;
              position: absolute;
              right: 30px;
              top: 25px;
              z-index: 101;
              cursor: pointer;
              display: none;
              height: 16px; /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
              width: 27px;
              border-top: 2px solid #fff;
              display: block;
              border: none;  
              height: 26px; /*AQUI ES DONDE SE PINTA EL BLOQUE*/
              top: 25px;
              outline: 10px solid transparent;
              background: transparent;
            }
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/uu1k5z8b/) is the working JSFiddle.